# Query SiteTree for archived pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have several pages in my site that are in an archived state but cannot see what Silverstripe uses to determine that a page is in an archived state.

Is there a function that I can use to determine whether a page is in an archived state, something like

```
foreach (SiteTree::get() as $page) {
    echo $page->isArchived();
}
```

Or some sort of attribute that I can query by to return all archived pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback to filter out the archived pages, something like this:

```
$allPages = Versioned::get_including_deleted('SiteTree');
$deletedPages = $allPages->filterByCallback(function($page) {
    // Doesn't exist on either stage or live
    return $page->getIsDeletedFromStage() && !$page->getExistsOnLive();
});
```

This code above is exactly what the filter in the CMS does (eg. when you filter for archived pages)

I guess it would also be doable with a DB query, but it's not going to be a simple check for a field but most likely a query that consists of multiple subqueries.

Comment: Do you have to disable `Versioned` filtering first?

Comment: @wmk you're right of course… `SiteTree::get` isn't going to cut it… I changed the answer